# Question about prove if $D$ was open, $f$ continuous and bounded, $f(p)\ge 0$ for all $p\in D$, then $∬_D f=0$, imply $f(p)=0$ for all p.

Tags: real-analysis

I was doing the homework about the question that if $D$ was open, $f$ continuous and bounded, $f(p)\ge 0$ for all $p\in D$, then $∬_D f=0$, imply $f(p)=0$ for all p.

I finished the prove to accommodate the condition as much as possible. However, I still didn't understand why the question provided so much condition.

For instance, my professor told me that "$D$ being open" was just a lazy way to say that $D$ has some area($A(D)\neq 0$), and I did see some sort of convenient with that condition.

However, the work I did in the proof was through $f$ being continuous, and I think that's enough.

I didn't quite get why the question gave the condition of $f$ being bounded. Why $f$ being bounded was given in this question? Wasn't $f$ being continuous was enough?

Comment: it is difficult to say, without seeing your proof. Your teacher may say that $f$ is bounded, just to be able to use that the integral exists. If $f(p)>0$ for some $p$ then there is some $a>0$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ (of positive area $A$) such that $f(x)\ge a$ for all $x\in U$ and then the integral would be at least $a\cdot A >0$

Comment: Which integral are you working with? If you are working with the Riemann integral and $D$ is a general open set, it is not enough to require that $f$ is continuous for the integral to exist. Think about the one-dimensional case working on $(0,1)$ with a function such as $1/x$.

Comment: It was about Riemann integral under Jordan measurable. The book only said "$D$ is open", but I assume it meant in $R^k$ where $k\ge 2$. When $f$ was continuous, and say a point $p$ such that $f(p)=M>0$, we could obtain a neighborhood $U$ such that $f(q)>0$ for all $q\in U$. proved.

Comment: @JC: Then the conditions are there to make sure the integral is actually defined. Think about $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1) \times (0,1)$.

Comment: But there was a theorem in the book said that "$Theorem 1:$ If $f$ is continuous on $R$, then $\iint_R f$ exits."

Comment: Perhaps the theorem assumes that $R$ is compact (closed and bounded). You could say more, namely obtain a neighborhood $U$ such that $f(q)\ge \frac M2$ for all $q\in U$